# Why does wrapping a script block into a commandlet function swallow all output?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal, powershell-7

Below script works perfectly fine when it is directly executed from a .ps1 file, but ever since i put it in a .psm1 file the function still works, but does no longer redirect the output from `&dotnet ...` to the output. I am looking for a way to make it print its output from within the function too. Moving it back to the ps1 is not an option.

I have tried a variation of

### Attempts

```
& dotnet *>&1
& dotnet | Out-Host
& dotnet | Write-Host
```

but apparently my powershell knowledge is too limited here.

### functions.psm1:

```
function Build-Android {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $KeyStorePath, 

        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $SignPassword, 

        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $ProjectPath, 

        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $PublishDirectory
    )

    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PCR3PW', $SignPassword, 'Process')

    $keyAlias = "PCR3"
    $keyPass = "env:PCR3PW"
    $storePass = "env:PCR3PW"

    # https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli 
    $publishCode = "dotnet publish $ProjectPath -f net7.0-android -c Release -o `"$PublishDirectory`" -p:AndroidKeyStore=true -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=$KeyStorePath -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=$keyAlias -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=$keyPass -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=$storePass"
    Write-Host "$publishCode" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen

    #Invoke-Expression -Command $publishCode -ErrorAction Stop
    &dotnet publish $ProjectPath -f net7.0-android -c Release -o `"$PublishDirectory`" -p:AndroidKeyStore=true -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=$KeyStorePath -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=$keyAlias -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=$keyPass -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=$storePass
    
    if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)    
        throw "There was an issue running the specified dotnet command."

    $apk = Get-ChildItem "$PublishDst" -Filter "*.apk" | %{$_.FullName}

    return $apk
}
```

### MyScript.ps1:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Signing password for publish process")]
    [string]$SignPassword,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Destination folder for APK publish")]
    [string]$PublishDst
)

Import-Module ".\functions.psm1"

$keyStore = [System.Uri]::new([System.Uri]::new("$PSScriptRoot\.", [System.UriKind]::Absolute), [System.Uri]::new("PCR3.keystore", [System.UriKind]::Relative)).LocalPath
$apkProject = [System.Uri]::new([System.Uri]::new("$PSScriptRoot\.", [System.UriKind]::Absolute), [System.Uri]::new("..\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj", [System.UriKind]::Relative)).LocalPath

$apkPath = Build-Android -KeyStorePath $keyStore -SignPassword $SignPassword -ProjectPath $apkProject -PublishDirectory $PublishDst
```

### References checked

I have looked into this to look for clues on how to redirect my output:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.3

### Underlying issue

The cause of this apparently in some way is Terminal. While $PSVersionTable is the same as PS Core 7 - Terminal produces no output from the & expression while powershell itself does.

Comment: How are you importing and invoking the `Build-Android` function? FWIW there's a syntax error in your function, there's a missing `{` after `if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added the calling code. { is optional with PS7 i guess. this code runs without issue for me

Comment: Ahh, you must be running 7.4-preview

Comment: 7.2.16 actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the call site:

> ```
> $apkPath = Build-Android -KeyStorePath $keyStore -SignPassword $SignPassword -ProjectPath $apkProject -PublishDirectory $PublishDst
> ```

You're assigning the output from `Build-Android` to the local variable `$apkPath`, so that's where the output will end up.

If you want to sidestep the normal flow of output and instead print it to the host application immediately, use `Out-Host`:

```
&dotnet publish $ProjectPath -f net7.0-android -c Release -o `"$PublishDirectory`" -p:AndroidKeyStore=true -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=$KeyStorePath -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=$keyAlias -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=$keyPass -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=$storePass |Out-Host
```

---

Here's a simplified example showing the effect with `ping.exe` instead:

```
PS ~> @'
>> function f {
>>   [CmdletBinding()]
>>   param()
>>
>>   ping.exe 1.1.1.1 -n 1 |Out-Host
>>
>>   return 'Not from ping'
>> }
>> '@ |Set-Content myModule.psm1
PS ~> Import-Module myModule.psm1 -Force
PS ~> $functionOutput = f

Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 1.1.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 13ms, Maximum = 13ms, Average = 13ms
PS ~> $functionOutput
Not from ping
```

As you can see, the output piped to `Out-Host` is written directly to the host application's screen buffer immediately as `f` executes, whereas the regular output that isn't ends up in the variable.

Comment: That's only where the returned value will land actually. I tried Out-Host without success. Did you verify your answer? This probably should also work if you remove my code and do &ping or something

Comment: @Dbl You seem to have misunderstood the function of the `return` keyword in PowerShell - any output not otherwise redirected or assigned will "bubble up" to the caller, regardless of whether it was part of a `return` statement

Comment: I'm aware of that. My issue is not the return value of the function. i need the output of &dotnet ... to land in the host output. If i strip all my code bare and just use &ping i can reduce the problem. as soon as i am in a function block my command no longer ends up in the host.

Comment: @Dbl Even when you pipe to `Out-Host`?

Comment: Oddly enough - Yes. I remember a bunch of powershell scripts where i have done pretty much that whenever i wanted to capture the output of a & expression. But for some reason whenever i do it from cmdlet it does not work. As if there is some attribute i am missing or something

Comment: @Dbl I've added the output from my shell when I do the same with `ping`.

Comment: @Dbl Does the problem only occur when `dotnet publish` fails? If so, combine output redirection with `Out-Host`: `& dotnet ... *>&1 | Out-Host`

Comment: Now you're almost where i am - if you do the exact same thing from a powershell window after importing the module it will also forward the output - however if you execute a ps1 which references the module -> no output from & . If i do it like you do it it works (but that does not work for CI, where i want to reference a ps1)

Comment: @Dbl Did that too, results are as expected - output piped to `Out-Host` show up immediately

Comment: Okay... Terminal powershell: no output. ps7core: works. Both give the same result for $PSVersionTable. Thanks for helping through verification